# Set of real numbers in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I tried to use the command `\mathbb {R}` in order to get the `set of real numbers` symbol in LaTeX. But, I just simply get the normal `R`.

How can I represent the set of real numbers in LaTeX?

Comment: Please stop using the [tag:tex-core] tag for all your questions, it hasn't been appropriate for any of them I think.

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: It seems pointless to say it again but your question should include a _complete_ _small_ document that shows the problem. `\mathbb{R}` should either produce a double struck R or an error message, if it does not there is an error in code you have not shown. Please edit your question to include sufficient information that it may be answered.

Comment: @ Ian Thompson. Thanks a lot. That worked...

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Thanks for your note. What tags do you recommend? For instance, to this question let's say

Comment: @Simplicity so your question was totally misleading, `\mathbb` did not generate a normal R it generated an **error**

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I think some IDEs have an option to run in nonstop mode by default, in which case you do get a normal R. This is one reason I consider IDEs to be the work of Satan.

Comment: @IanThompson: But all IDEs show a list of errors after compiling. But there are users who ignore them and think the document is fine as long a PDF comes out …